# Low performance between VMware and backupexec

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, backupexec

I have a dedicated HP backup server, connected to an HP autoloader(SAS).
The server is connected through 1 Gbps (network interfaces bridged) IPv4 to the network, where I from BackupExec 2010 R3 connected to my virtual environment, runnning a fully patched ESXi 4.1, with a vCenter server, connected to a SAN (SAS).

When doing a backup job, backing the vmdk of any VM up, I get a peaking performance around 220mb/min. When backing up the dedicated server it self, I use the full speed which is +5000 mb/min.
I know I can't transfer the data faster than 1 gbps, but still.. The 220mb/min is 0,003 gbps?!
is it really suppose to be that low? What could I possible be doing wrong?

The transport mode is set to NDB since we are using the network, and GTR is disabled all the way through.

I've tried both over vcenter, and through the host it self - same performance. 
When copying a file from a VM to the dedicated host, I get full speed (1 Gbps).

Comment: Is there any reason you're not backing up the virtual machines from within the guests using the appropriate BackupExec agents?

Comment: You mean, using the windows agent, and backing up the whole filesystem, instead of the VMDK (snapshot)? - I'm quite new in this field, so I apologize if it seems stupid, or simply straight forward to you? Any help is appreciated.
What I've done is simply taking the backup wiz, Choosing VMware Center and ESX server, picking the vCenter server, and the VM I want to back backup. Should I choose a remote windows computer instead, choose the one, and tick off the drives, system state ect. instead?

Comment: Try it. I tend to want to be able to recover files rather than the entire system. This process may work better for you.

Comment: I dont know about Vmware byt using hyper-v theres an agent you can install that will let you backup the entire vm as well as do granular file restores, kind of the best of both worlds.

Comment: I get full speed from backing up the filesystem as ewwhite suggests. But when backing up the VMDK from the vCenter / ESXi, it's still really slow. - Any suggestions? 
What I want is snapshot backup, being able to use GTR.

Comment: If you have the AVVI Agent installed, then you get backups of the vmdks through vCenter integration and you can turn on GRT within the Backup Policy.  Speed seems to be a persistent issue in this configuration, though.